# "Back" doesn't work when start the mapview activity

Tags: java, android

why my back button doesn't function in google map activity ?
already include:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()  {return;}
```

but still doesn't work.

Comment: if your using Android 1.x then use onKeyDown()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Or this pre API level 5:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your implementation here
        // finish(); - to exit the Activity
        return true; // shows you consumed the event with your implementation
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

write

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

or

```
this.finish();
```

instead of return;